# How to prove this mapping is algebraic?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

Suppose $x = u + v$ and $y = \frac{1}{uv}.$

How do I analyze whether there exists a finite number of algebraic mappings, let's call such mappings $R_1$ and $R_2,$ such that these functions algebraic in $x$ and $y$ can isolate each term, whether there exists
$$R_1(x,y) = u \ \text{and} \ R_2(x,y) = v?$$

I don't know hardly anything about algebraic geometry so this is a new type of analysis to me.

Since $x$ and $y$ are both algebraic in $u$ and $v,$ perhaps one can claim there exists polynomials $P_1$ and $P_2$ such that $P_1(x,u+v) = 0$ and $P_2(y,\frac{1}{uv})= 0,$ then that
$P_1 + P_2 = 0,$ I'm unsure where to go from here though.

Is there a way to establish $u+v$ and $\frac{1}{uv}$ are linearly independent in some sense, but that because they're both algebraic, they could both construct any expression polynomial in $u$ and $v$ with algebraic functions?

Is algebraic geometry even the appropriate category for this? I might add functional analysis.

Comment: Why don't you just solve the equations for $u$ and $v$?

Comment: Also, no, its not for functional analyisis. Do you even know what functional analysis is about?

Comment: @AitorIribarLopez but I think that's what I'm trying to do. I assure you such a mapping, if algebraic, is complicated, all I'm trying to do is prove it exists. Otherwise, can you please illustrate your suggestion? I'm loosely familiar with functional analysis, typically relating to functional equations and calculus on Banach spaces, typically function spaces segueing into variation calculus.

Comment: You put $v = 1/yu$ on the first equation and solve the quadratic equation in $u$. You get functions with square roots. That is normal

Comment: Okay, I'll give it a try and see if it works, thank you for the suggestion. However, what I'm still looking for is: without explicitly solving such equations, how does one determine the desired mappings exist in algebraic terms? Because there's more complicated combinations of $u$ and $v$ out there and sometimes one stumbles into cases where a result is impossible or only true for when the coefficients are 0 and the likes.

Comment: Hint: inverse function theorem! :)  (Google-able)

Comment: Okay, I'm looking at the inverse function theorem, but which if the 4 variables are you recommending I differentiate by? Or are you proposing a vector-valued function? In which case, what is the inverse of a vector valued function?

Comment: You have a situation like $f(u,v)=(x,y)$, and want to find (at least in certain possibly-restricted regions) an inverse function $g$ such that $g((f(u,v))=(u,v)$ and so on. The inverse function theorem gives a sufficient condition in terms of the partial derivatives of $f$ with respect to its two inputs...

Comment: I did also take the liberty of changing the tag to "multivariate calculus", which is exactly what this is about. (Not functional analysis, and not really algebraic geometry, although analogous issues do arise in much fancier settings in algebraic geometry.)

Comment: Is there a way to show these two expressions are "linearly independent" over some function space or polynomial space in some sense, thus there must be a way to construct $u$ and $v$?

Answer (score 1):

To make a quick application of the standard inverse function theorem in this example, consider $F(u,v)=(f(u,v),g(u,v))=(u+v,1/uv)$. Near specific $(u_o,v_o)$, there will be a ("local") differentiable inverse function if $\det\pmatrix{f_u & g_u \cr f_v & g_v}\not=0$, where the subscripts are partial derivatives. Here this condition is
$$
0 \;\not=\; \det\pmatrix{ 1 & {-1\over u^2v} \cr 1 & {-1\over uv^2}}
\;=\; {-1\over uv^2} - {-1\over u^2v}
\;=\; {1\over u^2v^2}\cdot (v-u)
$$
This is non-zero for $u\not=v$, and away from $u=0$ or $v=0$, so in that region there is a (local!) inverse function, by the theorem.

Yes, this guarantees *existence* without worrying about formulas.